# Linear dependence of geometric vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

We know that any four geometric vectors are linearly dependent. **Is it true that any n (n >= 4 ) vectors will be linearly dependent?** After all, if four vectors are linearly dependent, then one of the vectors is expressed in terms of the others: $\overline{a} = \alpha*\overline{b} + \beta*\overline{c} + \gamma*\overline{d}$

Then if we add any fifth vector (and so on), then the new system will also be linearly dependent, because:
$\overline{a} = \alpha*\overline{b} + \beta*\overline{c} + \gamma*\overline{d} + 0*\overline{e}$

Comment: As you correctly observed, any sub-family of a linearly independent family of vectors is also linearly independent, or conversely, any super-family of a linearly dependent family of vectors is also linearly dependent.

Comment: If you add any vector to a linearly dependent set of vectors, you will get a linearly dependent vector, as Hagen points out, and as you also demonstrate in your answer. It is not true that *any* set of at least as many vectors will be linearly dependent. For example, if $e_1, \ldots, e_5$ are the standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^5$, then $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_1 + e_2 + e_3$ is linearly dependent, but the basis $e_1, \ldots, e_5$ is a larger linearly independent set.

Comment: To be clear... you say "*we know that any four* **geometric** *vectors are linearly dependent.*"  What you really mean is that any four (*or more*) vectors from specifically $\Bbb R^3$, from specifically three dimensional Euclidean space, will be dependent.  We can work in more exotic contexts of course such as working in four-dimensional space where we could very well have had four independent vectors...